# How to achieve the following behavior by using the @Cacheable annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

Let's assume that I have a method that fetches data from Mongo which can be cached into redis.

```
@Cacheable
public List<Values> cacheValues(List<String> input){
     // code that fetches the list based on input from mongodb
}
```

The problem is that there is a list of documents that corresponds to each particular input in mongo db. When fetched from mongo, all lists are merged into a single list. Is there any way we can tell the @Cacheable annotation that data has to be persisted and fetched in the same way? or is there any way we can customize the @Cacheable to be able to use our own redis operations for fetching and persisting?. I am using spring data redis.

2nd question: How can I create a key based on the values in input. For example:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "cach1", key = "input[0] + …. input[input.size-1]")
    
        public List<Values> cacheValues(List<String> input){
    
             // code that fetches the list based on input from mongodb
    
        }
```

Comment: "When fetched from mongo, all lists are merged into a single list.". Do you mean that the result list items of multiple calls (e.g. when invoking `cacheValues([a,b,c]) and cacheValues([d,e,f])` ) are to be cached as a single list [a,b,c,d,e,f] ?

Comment: correct. So for a third call with input [c,d,e] we can fetch from redis directly and not from different cached entries such as that a,b,c -> value1,  d,e,f -> value 2, c,d,e -> value3

Comment: @Fernando BTW what would be the cache key? This looks to be not directly solvable, for example, you can store the result of `a,b,c` and `d,e,f` as `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` assume `[1,2,3]` is the result for  `a,b,c` and `[4,5,6]` for `d,e,f`.  When you make a call for `c,d,e` you need to check whether the result for `c,d,e` in the cache or not, your cache key keeps changing, I think you should do all the operation inside the `cacheValues` method. This method should do all stuff to see what'll data missing, you can consider storing the result of a,b,c to an individual `key,value`  instead of a list.